# simplexml_load_string() not returning any elements

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm pulling some medication data from the NLM (national library of medicine). I'm trying to convert it's result which is an xml string:

```
<SpellAid>
<Chemical>
<Name>Albuterol</Name>
<CAS>18559-94-9</CAS>
</Chemical>
<Chemical>
<Name>Albuterol [USAN]</Name>
<CAS>18559-94-9</CAS>
</Chemical>
<Chemical>
<Name>dl-Albuterol</Name>
<CAS>18559-94-9</CAS>
</Chemical>
</SpellAid>
```

When I do:

```
exit(var_dump(simplexml_load_string($response)->children()));
```

I get:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#75 (0) { }
```

doing

```
exit(var_dump(simplexml_load_string($response)));
```

gets me

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#56 (0) { }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I thought that possibly I needed to utf8_encode the xml, no dice. Simplexml_load_string also is nice enough to prepend the proper xml DTD.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, for reference, I have attempted to reference children from:

```
$response->children()->SpellAid;
$response->children()->SpellAid[0];
$response->children()->Chemical;
```

$response->Chemical is not being returned as an array. $response->SpellAid is in fact a simplexml element, but then ->Chemical members are NULL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you don't get bonus points for cramming as many lines of code as possible into one line.

Let's break this down into something more readable and maintainable:

```
$response = ...; // your XML input

$xml = simplexml_load_string_response($response);

$chemicals = $xml->Chemical;

// $chemicals stores an array of XMLSimpleElement objects.
// You can work with them like this:

foreach($chemicals as $chemical) {
    echo $chemical->Name;
    echo $chemical->CAS;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell $response->Chemical is not being returned as an array but as an element. Attempting to iterate through it doesn't work, the loop is never entered. $response->SpellAid is in fact a simplexml element, so I thought $response->SpellAid->Chemical would work, but it's giving me NULL.

Comment: Also, the aesthetics of the code sort of dropped off once things didn't work the way I expected them to.

Comment: Well I copied your code, instead of re-writing, and it worked. I genuinely don't know what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the help I suppose.